# In feature selection, what is the reason for considering removing low variance features?

Tags: variance, predictive-models, feature-selection

I've overheard a few times that when doing feature selection, one should look at features with low variance  and consider removing them.

(My guess is that  if we have a dataset of 100 observations and a feature has low variance, it might mean that the feature might not carry much information as the feature's value is the same for all the observations and thus isn't informative i.e. the feature is nearly constant across observation.)

Comment: Variance is about capacity for information.  If you have 10 columns of inputs that are effectively constant, then they might all be adding the same thing to the fit: nothing.  You have to prove it is truly effectively constant because slow change can still carry information.  Also, if you understand the "physics" then you can remove very high frequency signals, ones that are much more than the characteristic frequency, because they can be mostly noise.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "low" variance?  What is your criterion or threshold for a variance to be low?  Note that in any predictive or regression model, a characterization of "low variance" that does not relate to some property of the *relationship* between the variable and the response can't be useful.

Comment: Because different variables typically are measured in different units that are incommensurate, it can be hard to know what "low" variance actually is in any real situation. In addition, a variable that truly has low variance might nonetheless be quite valuable if the association is sufficiently strong.

Comment: information theoretic feature selection might be useful http://proceedings.mlr.press/v5/brown09a/brown09a.pdf

Comment: @whuber, That's part of what was irking me, I've heard it said quite a few times without "low variance" being explicitly related to the relationship between the variance and the model.

Comment: "Low variance" could have meaning in a particular context, but as a general characterization it's meaningless.  Because you haven't provided any context, we are left guessing.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine the limiting case in which you have a feature $x$ which is constant (no variance) will it have an effect on the output $y$? If $y$ is changing, then $x$ should be irrelevant in the relationship because it is constant.

This is the reason, why people tend to discard variables with low variance. The problem is that there is no rigorous method to determine if a feature has a "low" variance. Comparison with other features is often difficulty because they might have different scales (eg. if you compare the variance of the length of screws with the variance of weights of ships than you will have different scales). A $z$-transform will impose same scale and directly normalize the variance. Hence, $z$-transforms (mean = 0, variance = 1 for all variables) don't really help at this comparison.

One way to investigate this problem would be to look at the distribution of values. If you see a variable that has a very sharp spike (almost only one value is present) then you might consider discarding it.

To be quite honest I seldomly saw a feature in practice that had such a pathological distribution (no one would invest time and money to measure something that is constant all the time). These zero variance variables are often meta informations that were added because they were easy to gather. Hence, in my opinion, this condition is only used to rule out such pathological cases, where the variance is $0$. In all other cases, you must further investigate the variable.

Comment: For categorical features, or semi-discrete features like your distribution example, this is at least common enough to show up as `caret::nearZeroVar`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-76/topics/nearZeroVar

Comment: Just to check my understanding, the reason the z-transform isn't useful in this comparison is that after the z-transforming each feature, all of the transformed variable will have a variance of 1, right?

Comment: @stochasticmrfox: Correct, the $z$-transform will imply a mean of zero and a variance of 1. Hence, it is not possible to rule out problematic variances by this transform.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is why I do it. If they have low variance, they likely won't improve your model anyway, so it's safe to remove them. For example, in MNIST, pixels that almost always background. Or some questionnaire items that are nearly always false and so on. Of course, 'variance' is not a good measure for any modality, and it might not be comparable between features.

Another reason is that low/no variance features sometimes make algorithms crash or fail to converge without any meaningful error message. When this happens, my first instinct is to remove invariant features and try again.

Lastly, it can reduce the dimensionality of your problem and make your model fit faster with less memory consumption.

Comment: For this answer to have any meaning at all, you need to address the question raised in the comments: namely, what do *you* mean by "low" variance?

Comment: "Or some questionnaire items that are nearly always false and so on." These can often be the most informative features! Consider: "have you ever been convicted of driving while intoxicated" in an insurance application.

Comment: @whuber I don't know what is the confusion. By low variance I mean literally variance that is low, i.e. close to 0 or 0. Or am I missing something? I even gave few examples, pixels that are always white, symptoms that are always 0 etc.

Comment: @MatthewDrury it's possible, but you still have to have enough data to estimate it's effect. We do depression ressearch and I am sure suicide attempts are related to many things, but we have only 5 people with preious suicide attempts so there is not uch to do with that variable for the analysis, OFC, there is a lot to do with that variable for a clinitian

Comment: Yes, you are missing the fundamental fact that the size of a number is never unequivocally "low" or otherwise: it depends on the unit of measurement and some standard or comparison.  For instance, is $0.01$ "low"?  How about if that is the weight of a chicken in tons?  Until you explain clearly, in a way that can be quantified, what you mean by "low," then it is impossible to interpret your answer in any definite way.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by "Of course, 'variance' is not a good measure for any modality, and it might not be comparable between features." Variances of all pixel values are comparable to each other, variances of all likert like items are comparable to each other, chickens in tons are not comparable to annual income in pennies.